# In MySQL, Copy a row record from the same table only if that row doesn't exist?

Tags: mysql

I was trying to figure out how to copy a row record from the same table only if that row doesn't exist, but solutions I found was just a part of it. Like, 'copying a record', or 'insert if not exists'. So I tried to merge those answers to make mine, but... I think I only made some abomination code.

Let's see this

```
INSERT INTO LCL
SELECT * FROM LCL WHERE (UID = 0 AND NAME = 'S_TYPE')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM LCL WHERE UID = 11 AND NAME = 'S_TYPE' LIMIT 1);
```

There is a default format records with `UID = 0`. And if there is no record with `NAME = S_TYPE`, copy record with `NAME = S_TYPE AND UID = 0`, and change `UID` into 11. The record should copy the data of all columns. So I tried to use SELECT * but not sure if it is right.

I'm sure I screwed things up with two `WHERE`s...

Comment: I think it is strange to insert data into a table sourcing from the same table. What is your goal? Maybe what you really want to do is `UPDATE` instead?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a `WHERE` then the follow up should be `AND`. I don't think you really need the parentheses on the first `WHERE` though so:

```
INSERT INTO LCL
SELECT * FROM LCL 
 WHERE UID = 0 AND NAME = 'S_TYPE'
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM LCL WHERE UID = 11 AND NAME = 'S_TYPE' LIMIT 1);
```